# Unable to create dynamic formula for average in my excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in a column from H5 and I5 and I want to calculate Average for n numbers (value of n is given in E2) and display the value in column J. value of n will vary from 2 to 14. I'm able to calculate the first value dynamically but couldn't calculate second and later values. I couldn't shift the average for second and third values as I have to take average values from current row to n values above but my formula always calculate average from 1st row to n row. So, how do I shift my average for 2nd value from (n+1)th row to 2nd row and so on.

This is my formula =IF($E$2=COUNT($H$6:H7),(AVERAGE($H$6:H7)/AVERAGE($I$6:I7)),"") For example, for 2 Average, it is calculating correctly 1st data in 2nd row, but couldn't give value for 3rd row and beyond for same Average. For 1st data it's displaying correctly the average of 1st and 2nd row from H Column and dividing it by average of 1st and 2nd row from I Column. 2nd data which I'm unable to calculate dynamically should display average of 2nd and 3rd row from H Column and dividing it by average of 2nd and 3rd row from I Column. This should continue for other averages as well like 5/10 whatever it may be.
[Excel sheet Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu0FP.png)

Comment: Please provide some sample data within your code (best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)) --> it is then much easier to help you because we don't have to create the sample data on our own. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Pls. try this `=IF($E$2=COUNT(OFFSET(H6,0,0,$E$2)),AVERAGE(OFFSET(H6,0,0,$E$2))/AVERAGE(OFFSET(I6,0,0,$E$2)),"")`

Comment: @Ike PFA the link of the file. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f2LzZ_uSDUEUfBNcnukGb6lWmDaDq8mn/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=114893496818362789187&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Please read [ask] and [repro]! You should add sample data to your question - don't point to a document - nobody will open that. If you need a google spreadsheet solution: change the tags of the question.

Comment: @Black cat, Thanks for your suggestion. It's working better than mine but needs some changes. Currently when I entered this formula in 2nd row cell and dragged it to last it's giving me average value for 5 from 2nd row itself and leaving the last rows blank. What I want is that for average of 5, First 4 rows should be blank and it should start displaying value from 5th row and then go on displaying the value till last row.

Comment: @Ike, sorry for confusing you with my questions as I'm new to this portal. I need answer for Excel only. I uploaded it on gdrive. I will try to rephrase my question. Suppose column A is having any random values from 2nd row A2 to 100th row A100. I want to write formula in 2nd column B from 3rd row B3, such that whatever value I enter in C1 like 5 should display me average of A2 to A6 in B6. B2 to B5 should be blank and B7 should display the average of A3 to A7 and so on till the last row.

Comment: I see. Try this `=IF($E$2=COUNT(OFFSET(H6,0,0,-$E$2)),AVERAGE(OFFSET(H6,0,0,-$E$2))/AVERAGE(OFFSET(I6,0,0,-$E$2)),"")`

Comment: @Black cat, That's working perfectly fine. You are genius.